# A question about freeCodeCamp Challenge : Arguments Optional

Tags: javascript, arguments

I'm stuck with one of curriculum in freeCodeCamp.org
https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/arguments-optional

The below code is what I wrote. 
In that code, addTogether(2)(3) should be 5.
But instead of that, addTogether(2)(3) is "undefined"

what's the problem?

I read all hints from freecodecamp forum. But I don't get it.

```js
function addTogether() {

  var checkNum = function(x) {
    if (typeof x === "number") {
      return x
    } else {
      return undefined
    }
  }

  if (arguments.length > 1) {
    if (checkNum(arguments[0]) !== undefined && checkNum(arguments[1]) !== undefined) {
      return arguments[0] + arguments[1]
    } else {
      return undefined
    }

  } else {
    var a = arguments[0]
    if (checkNum(a) === undefined) {
      return undefined
    } else {
      return function(args2) {
        args2 + a
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}

console.log(addTogether(2)(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your returned function doesn't have a return value.  You could use

```
  return function(args2) {
     return args2 + a
  }
```

Or

```
  return (args2) => args2 + a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function addTogether(a,b) {

    
  
    if (arguments.length==2){
      if (typeof a == "number" && typeof b == "number"){
        return a + b;
      }
    }

    if(arguments.length==1){
      if (typeof a == "number"){
        return function(b){
          if (typeof b == "number"){
            return a + b;
          }
        };
      }
    }

}
```